# Angular - Tomcat : Session expiration on backend, session tracking on frontend

Tags: angularjs, session, tomcat

My angular app uses analytics to save a lot many things about user behaviour. The session id is also saved as part of this information.

Session is handled on the backend by tomcat.
Consider this scenario :

1. The user clicks on the search button to perform a search.
2. The analytics track that the search button was clicked, while the
   session id was : "asvw4t".
3. The request gets to the backend and the session has expired. The backend creates a new session (may require login from user), and sends the response back to the frontend. The new session id is : "wprkfs" .
4. now further calls will have the new session id in analytics.

But now i can't co-relate my last call before the session expiration , and the first call after the new session is generated, on analytics.
Is this a usual scenario ? Or am i doing something wrong ?

Comment: I think that there are some options, 1. try to increase the session timeout , 2.  Per every request correlate by userid and sessionid  3.  Using an stateless approach like JWT.